# Resolve in an Angular route

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have the following code on the resolve member in a route:

```
resolve: {
    loadData: function ($q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var fbRef = new Firebase("https://myPathToFirebase");
        var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef, function (error, user) {
            console.log('resolving. ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
            deferred.resolve();
        });
        console.log('returning..');
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

The callback within FirebaseSamleLogin is simplified for clarity
The logging shows that the code runs as expected. User-id and provider ( facebook) is printed in the callback.
My problem is that the deferred.resolved() is not working. The code will not continue to run the controller code and render the template. Exactly as if the deferred was never resolved.
I’m kind of stuck here and any help / suggestions would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Use more verbose traces like `console.log("Returning promise..." , deferred.promise)` and let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to wrap the resolve() in $apply() like this

```
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef, function (error, user) {
    console.log('resolving. ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea and I would like to try. However, this code runs within the config function and the $scope service cannot be injected in this context.
I know for sure that  deferred. Resolved() does not work when invoked within the  FirebaseSimpleLogin.  When I move the deferred.resolved()  outside the callback, it works fine
Of course, the code makes no sense when moved out of the callback

Answer (score 0):

And if wrap resolve() in $apply() as @zsong wrote but with $rootscope ?

```
resolve: {
    loadData: function ($q,$rootscope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var fbRef = new Firebase("https://myPathToFirebase");
        var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef, function (error, user) {
            console.log('resolving. ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
            $rootscope.$apply(deferred.resolve());
        });
        console.log('returning..');
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```